# Pagination using Rest API

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make pagination using restful api and here is my js code for displaying data. I have to display only 6 data that are coming from json api.

```
   success: function(data){
    var arr = data.data;
    var htmlText = '';
        for ( var key in arr ) {
            htmlText += '<div class="feed-element">';
            htmlText += '<a href="profile.html" class="pull-left">';
            htmlText += '<img alt="image" class="img-circle" src= '+ arr[key].image +' >';
            htmlText += '</a>';
            htmlText += '<div class="media-body ">';
            htmlText += '';
            htmlText += '<p class="user-name"> Name: ' + arr[key].name + '</p>';
            htmlText += '<p class="user-loc"> Location: ' + arr[key].location + '</p>';
            htmlText += '<p class="user-desc"> Description: ' + arr[key].description + '</p>';
            htmlText += '<p class="user-created"> Created at: ' + arr[key].created_at + '</p>';
            htmlText += '</div>';
            htmlText += '</div>';
        }

        $('.feed-activity-list').append(htmlText);
    }
```

And this is my json data and here is total_count for pagination.

```
"status": 200,
"data": [
    {
        "name": "virendra rajpurohit ",
        "location": "Kanodiya purohitan ",
        "description": "I m show happy.. rajpurohitaap downloads..",
        "image": "https://rajpurohit.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/images/18770_20150505071218.jpg",
        "created_by": 52952,
        "users_name": "Virendra rajpurohit",
        "comment_count": 0
    },
    {
        "name": "Prakash Rajpurohit",
        "location": "Asotra",
        "description": "Jay datari saa",
        "image": "https://rajpurohit.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/images/26457_20150505070131.jpg",
        "created_by": 55752,
        "users_name": "Amarsingh Rajpurohit",
        "comment_count": 0
    },
],
"total_count": 201
}
```

Now, please tell me what to do for pagination. I have no idea to deal with this. please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to maintain two variables and pass them to backend to retrieve concerned page. `pageNo` , `noOfRecords`

Comment: but json data is coming only total_count means total records. what to do for pageNo and number of records.?

Comment: ok. you want the pagination logic at client side or server side?

Comment: on client side and where to write the code for pagination?

Comment: ok then that would be a lot of code as , you need to implement for logic of pagination on JSON array plus the logic for showing page nos, prev , next buttons

Comment: You can refer bootstrap's grid with pagination, and get some idea of pagination from source code.

Comment: what is the length of `data array`?? do you want `client side pagination`??

Comment: yeah i want client side pagination and data array are infinite and i have to dispaly 6 records in a single page.